How tox create a fresh environments
Here is my workflow:
I have a requirements.txt file that includes tox and many other packages.
Run:
 python3 -m venv global_env  
 source global_env/bin/activate  
 pip install -r requirements 

I create a tox.ini as following and I call all the different env in the jenkinsfile which is really very nice:
[tox]
envlist = py3.10.12, linter, unit-tests, docs 
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
allowlist_externals = pytest, sphinx-build
deps = 
    -rrequirements.txt
[testenv:linter]
description = Run Black linter
deps  = 
    black
commands = 
    black mtqe/ --check 

[testenv:unit-tests]
description = Run unit tests
deps = 
    {[testenv]deps}
commands =
    pytest ./tests/ --disable-warnings

My understading is that tox will create a completly fresh environments and run the tests. However, it is not the case. All environments inherits from the global_env and I test that my removing some packages from the requirements.txt and I expect that some unit tests should fail but it does not fail. What is wrong in my understanding. How tox create an isolated environments then ?


My understading is that tox will create a completly fresh environments and run the tests. However, it is not the case. All environments inherits from the global_env

I'm sure tox create fresh environments. The root of you problem I think is allowlist_externals = pytest. You run pytest installed into the global_env and it imports everything from its environment, not from the one created by tox. To fix install pytest into the environments created by tox:
[tox]
envlist = py3.10.12, linter, unit-tests, docs 
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
allowlist_externals = sphinx-build
deps = 
    -rrequirements.txt

[testenv:linter]
description = Run Black linter
deps  = 
    black
commands = 
    black mtqe/ --check 

[testenv:unit-tests]
description = Run unit tests
deps = 
    {[testenv]deps}
    pytest
commands =
    pytest ./tests/ --disable-warnings

